# Finding a path using the Parents Array Recursively in Python

Tags: python, recursion, path-finding

So I have a task, that is, to write a function that takes a parents array produced by a traversal, a starting vertex, and an end vertex, and produces a path from the start vertex to the end vertex.

I have tried writing the code for this

```
def tree_path(parents, start, end):
    if ((start == end) or (end == -1)):
        return [start, end]
    else:
        return tree_path(parents, start, parents[end])
```

It doesn't do what I intended for it to do. I'm not very good at recursion. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is `parents[end]` a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try, assuming we want a list of all vertices from `start` to `end`, the following:

```
def tree_path(parents, start, end):
    if (start == end) or (end == -1):
        return [start]
    else:
        return tree_path(parents, start, parents[end]) + [end]
```

If `start` coincides with `end` then our path consists only of one vertex: `start`. Otherwise, we find the path from `start` to the parent of `end` and to this path we add the `end` node.

Answer (score 1):

You keep recursing until `start==end`, then return `[start,end]`. That's always `[start,start]` (because `start==end`), so you don't learn anything. You only need to return `[start]` in the first return statement, because returning `[start,end]` will return a list with the same element twice. The other return statement needs to add something, also; otherwise, you'll just return two elements: `return tree_path(parents, start, parents[end]) + [end]`

There's a problem with this, too, though (I assume). `parents[end]` is (I think) a list of parents. `tree_path()` just takes a single end node, though. You need to iterate over them to see which one works (if I'm wrong about it being a list, just ignore this part and use the code from above):

```
for i in parents[end]:
    path = tree_path(parents,start,i):
    if path:
        return path + [end]
```

This assumes `tree_path()` returns a false value when it can't find a path.  You'll need to check for `end` being the root node. I assume that's what the `end==-1` check does. Putting this together, you get something like this:

```
def tree_path(parents, start, end):
    if end==-1:
        return None
    if start==end:
        return [end]
    else:
        for i in parents[end]:
            path = tree_path(parents,start,i):
            if path:
                return path + [end]
```